# Use Twitter Bootstrap popover with Highcharts

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I am trying to implement **Twitter Bootstrap popover** component with **Highcharts** when a user hovers over a bar in my bar chart.  I cannot use the existing tooltip that is native to Highcharts because I want my user to interact with the content inside the popover which you cannot efficiently do with the Highcharts tooltip such as clicking on a link.

The issue I am having is accessing the individual `rect` DOM elements to add the necessary attributes such as `rel="popover"` and `data-content="foo"` that would make this work.

I have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axl163/L48xb/5/) where I have pseudocode for the hover over event.

I would greatly appreciate any advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Attach popover after chart is loaded
2. Make sure that popover is not appended inside SVG

   ```
       chart: {
           renderTo: 'container',
           type: 'bar',
           events: {
               load: function(e) {
                   $(".highcharts-tracker rect").popover({trigger:'hover', placement:'bottom', title:'Title!', content:'Content'}).hover(function() {
                       $('.popover').appendTo($(document.body));
                   });
               }
           }
       },
   ```

If you want it to trigger on click, then simply change it to:

```
                    $(".highcharts-tracker rect").popover({trigger:'click', placement:'bottom', title:'Title!', content:'Content'}).click(function() {
                        $('.popover').appendTo($(document.body));
                    });
```

You will have to further modify this code to suit your needs, but that should help you start.

Working example: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L48xb/9/)

Comment: Thanks Voitek! This is definitely going in the right direction :) Do you know how I can access the `series.point.marker` object using this method? I apologize for not adding this bit in my description.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to show popover when you hover over something else (not the bar?). If you just want to access series.points inside the event, then you can do that by accessing e.delegateTarget.series inside the hover/click event.

Comment: Yes, I am interested in accessing the point data in the series.  I'll give this a go tomorrow morning.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks...it worked!  Any chance that you can tweak this so it the popover works on the `click` event.  I tried changing the `trigger` to `click` but then the whole thing breaks.

Comment: @VoitekZylinski what if I need to show info according the selected serie/category? how can I know that i have selected the category asia and the serie 2008? if you have the answer please post it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018716/get-seriename-and-category-value-using-highcharts

Comment: can popover be came in correct position, means on click or hover  over column popover should come beside it not above as coming your jsFiddle. Thnaks