# get serieName and category value using highcharts

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts, popover

I am using basic column chart from highchart component, and one feature that I need to implement is draw a popup (using popover) with information related with the selected series and selected category. In the code below you can see that I am attaching popover component to every column:

```
load: function(e) {  
    $(".highcharts-tracker rect").hover(function() {                            
        $(this).attr('data-content',  
                'here should be a nice call to my web api method');
    }).popover({trigger:'hover', placement:'right'}).hover(function() {
```

As you see above, what I have done is the creation of the popup using popover component. My question now is related with get the series name and the category for the selected series in order to call to my web API method.  If you see image below, for the selected column I need to get the values (serie1, 2016).

Any ideas? JSFiddle: [Column chart](http://jsfiddle.net/rolandomartinezg/3M2zG/5/)

[image: Feature image]

Comment: Why not to use `tooltip: { formatter: function() { ... } }` function to customize the tooltip? Inside this function the `this` object is available which contains all information about selected column (including value, series name etc.). So default Highcharts tooltip may be customized. For example look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976955/redrawing-the-tooltip-inside-of-the-tooltip-positioner-callback.

Comment: By the way `this` object is also available in your function for event handling but all information you will have to find by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into the point events to detect when the mouse is over a series. At that point, you have access to the series name etc.

```
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function () {
                        $(".popover").text(
                        this.series.name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/65VtA/